# insertEmptyTimeRange to AVMutableCompositionTrack not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, video

I'm stitching videos together in an AVMutableCompositionTrack, using this:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *passThroughLayer = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
```

I'm also adding a CALayer with text and images to the composition, using an animationLayer.

At the beginning, I add 5 seconds of nothing to insert a title using insertEmptyTimeRange.

Up to here, everything's working fine.

Now I want to add some «nothing» to the end of the video, using insertEmptyTimeRange again - but that fails miserably.

```
CMTime creditsDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5, 600);

    CMTimeRange creditsRange = CMTimeRangeMake([[compositionVideoTrack asset] duration], creditsDuration);

    [compositionVideoTrack insertEmptyTimeRange:creditsRange];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertEmptyTimeRange:creditsRange];

    NSLog(@"credit-range %f from %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(creditsRange.duration), CMTimeGetSeconds(creditsRange.start));
    NSLog(@"Total duration %f", CMTimeGetSeconds([[compositionVideoTrack asset] duration]));
```

The insert-points are correct (first NSLog), but the total duration won't get extended...

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it seems to be impossible to add an empty timerange to the end of an AVMutableComposition.

This answer saved my life: [AVMutableComposition of a Solid Color with No AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871328/avmutablecomposition-of-a-solid-color-with-no-avasset)